# How do I flag user accounts for deletion?

Tags: support, user-accounts

There are several fly-by-night accounts created for the sole purpose of promoting Holocaust denial.

How do I flag them for deletion?

Specifically:

- https://history.stackexchange.com/users/22488/nrenene
- https://history.stackexchange.com/users/22484/fhrbebe

(probably more, moderators can easily find them by reviewing recently deleted questions)

Answer (score 5):

[Flag the posts](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/flagging) with a custom moderator flag. As a general rule, it's best to focus on content, not the person. If the moderators see enough flags on a particular user's posts, they can [suspend the user](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/). If the user truly produces nothing of value, the mods have the option of deleting the account.